# Xcode write NSLog result in UILabel

Tags: iphone, xcode, label, uilabel, nslog

I use `NSLog(@"%@");`

And the NSLog result is '23204239423'
I don't explain you why ... it's just an example.

I want the NSLog result appear in UILabel, is it possible ?

I tried : `Label.text = (@"%@");` , it doesn't work.

Do you know how i can do it ?

Thanks.

Comment: I assume you mean you do something like `NSLog(@"%@",someObject);`.  Doing `NSLog(@"%@"), will attempt to interpret whatever garbage follows the @"%@" string in storage as an object, and that's likely to fail -- or at best produce utter garbage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

NSLog usually takes a string like:

```
NSLog(@"%@", string);
```

So instead just do this:

```
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", string];
```

Comment: Yep, under the covers NSLog is using `stringWithFormat`.

Comment: But, of course, if all that's being done is to assign `string` to the label text (nothing else added), that can be done directly, without any hocus-pocus.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put a variable

```
NSString *text = @"My Text";
label.text = text;
```

Or

```
label.text = @"Your text";
```